# Is it possible to use a parent class method as a decorator for a child class method?

Tags: python, inheritance, decorator

I have two classes, `Manager` and `DataManager`, simplified in the example below:

```
import numpy as np

class Manager:
    def __init__(self, value, delay_init=True):
        self.value = value
        self.is_init = False
        self.data = None

        if not delay_init:
            self._initialize()

    @staticmethod 
    def delayed_init(fn):
        def wrapped_delayed_init(obj, *args, **kwargs):
            if not obj.is_init:
                obj.data = np.random.randn(obj.value, obj.value)
                obj.is_init = True

            return fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)

        return wrapped_delayed_init

    @delayed_init.__get__(object)
    def _initialize(self):
        pass


class DataManager(Manager):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__(value)

    @Manager.delayed_init
    def calculate_mean(self):
        return np.mean(self.data)

data_manager = DataManager(100)
assert data_manager.data is None
mean = data_manager.calculate_mean()
```

What my code needs to do is pass the method `calculate` as an argument to some other function as part of a test suite. In order to do this I need to create an instance of `DataManager`. What I must avoid is the time incurred by the full instance creation (since it involved downloading data), and so I delegate this task to some function in the parent class called `delayed_init`. There are a subset of methods belonging to `DataManager` that require this `delayed_init` to have been run, and so I choose to decorate them with `delayed_init` to ensure it is run whenever 1) another method requires it and 2) it has not already been run.

Now my problem: Currently it appears I need to explicitly define the decorator as `@Manager.delayed_init`, but this can be re-written as `@<parent>.delayed_init`. I would like to write it this way if possible given that in my opinion it is cleaner to not have to explicitly write out a given type if the type is always the parent. However, I cannot find a way to properly reference the parent class before an instance/object is created. Is it possible to access the parent class without the creation of any instances?

Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: the decorator is a static method. why have it be a class method? couldn't you just move this to the module level?

Comment: Did you try `self.delayed_init`? will `delayed_init` always only be *defined* in the parent?

Comment: @wwii self definitely won't be defined when defining the class so I don't think that would work, right?

Comment: but yeah @dyprious I don't think there's a way to do what you're trying to do, unless it's using some super magic metaclass thing that's over my head and probably won't lead to clear code anyway :)

Comment: Yep, self won't work

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Thanks for the input. I could certainly move it to the module level, that does work, but since it acts on a class and modifies its attributes, I wanted to keep it within the class. Moving it to the module level is about as clean as what I am doing now I suppose.

Comment: maybe. yeah that's more of an aesthetic choice and probably depends on how you envision people using this. to me, `delayed_init` seems like more of a general purpose decorator you're defining, and IMO it would be cleaner if you moved the random number generator into Manager.initialize, then make `delayed_init` just a class-agnostic decorator which runs an instance's `_initialize` method if present before executing the function. but that's getting more into [codereview.se] territory than SO :)